# How to Calculate Age from Year Only in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have the year a car was purchased in column A. For example, 2015. I'm trying to calculate the age of the vehicle comparing the year provided in column A to TODAY() in an arrayformula, like this...

`={"Vehicle Age";arrayformula(if(A2:A="",,(datedif(A2:A,today(),"Y"))))}`

For some reason, it gives me the number 115 as the result for every cell where a year has been specified. Any idea why? I can't seem to find an answer on this anywhere on the internets.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing apples and oranges here, so to speak.

Internally, Google Sheets sees all full dates as a number of days from an origin point of December 31, 1899. As such, the *year* 2015 on its own, in a comparison with a full date will be seen as two-thousand-fifteen days since December 31, 1899 (or July 7, 1905 — which was 115 some-odd years ago, as would be the case with any relatively recent year, because they'll all be interpreted in their raw form by Sheets as a cluster of days from late June to early July of 1905).

Instead, you want to compare the *years only*, which will mean extracting the year from TODAY(), since A2:A are already year-only numbers:

`={"Vehicle Age";arrayformula(if(A2:A="",,year(TODAY())-A2:A))}`

However, since any year's car models are actually released the year before, you may want to add a year to your formula:

`={"Vehicle Age";arrayformula(if(A2:A="",,year((TODAY())-A2:A)+1))}`

Of course, you *could* also have turned your A2:A years into real dates (e.g., January 1 of each year listed) and then used `datedif` as well:

`={"Vehicle Age";arrayformula(if(A2:A="",,datedif(DATE(A2:A,1,1),today(),"Y")))}`

... or with that extra year added ...

`={"Vehicle Age";arrayformula(if(A2:A="",,datedif(DATE(A2:A,1,1),today(),"Y")+1))}`

Comment: Thanks, Erik. The first formula worked for me. The second one returned 2016 for all the results, so I modified the formula to this and it worked. ={"Vehicle Age";arrayformula(if(A2:A="",,year(TODAY())-A2:A)+1)}. Thanks for your help.

Comment: As for why the second formula might not have worked for you, it's possible that your raw year data in A2:A are strings and not numbers. Hard to say without seeing an individual sheet and data. But the most important thing is that you now have a working solution. As they say, "If it ain't broke, don't fix it."

Answer (score 0):

```
={"Vehicle Age";arrayformula(if(A2:A="",,datedif(DATE(A2:A,1,1),today(),"Y")))}
```

Not working